# R - Phylogram labels to vector

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

If we plot a phylogram from hierarchical clustering using `ape` package

```
phy <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
plot(as.phylo(phy),direction="downwards")
```

Is there a way to extract the labels in to a vector in the same order they appear in the phylogram (read from left to right)?

If I try

```
phy$labels
```

I can get the labels out but they appear to be in a different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the additional `order` component, you can get them in the proper ordering

```
with(phy, labels[order])
# [1] "Maserati Bora"       "Chrysler Imperial"   "Cadillac Fleetwood" 
#  [4] "Lincoln Continental" "Ford Pantera L"      "Duster 360"         
#  [7] "Camaro Z28"          "Hornet Sportabout"   "Pontiac Firebird"   
# [10] "Hornet 4 Drive"      "Valiant"             "Merc 450SLC"        
# ...
```