# Order correlation heatmap with phylogram labels

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, r-corrplot

This is kinda continuing my earlier question [R - Phylogram labels to vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933994/r-phylogram-labels-to-vector)

I have a phylogram from a hierarchical cluster analysis

```
#Create data
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(10),x2=rnorm(10),x3=rnorm(10),x4=rnorm(10),
         x5=rnorm(10),x6=rnorm(10),x7=rnorm(10),x8=rnorm(10),x9=rnorm(10),
         x10=rnorm(10))
tdf <- t(df)

#Hierarchical clustering and label extraction
x <- hclust(dist(tdf),method="complete")
xlabels <- with(x,labels[order])

#Plot phylogram
library(ape)
plot(as.phylo(x),direction="downwards")
```

[image]

I then want to plot a correlation heatmap with `corrplot` and I wish to order the variables with `xlabels` (the phylogram labels).

I tried

```
cormat <- cor(df,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cormat,method="color",order=corrMatOrder(xlabels))
```

But it isn't working and gives me the following error

> Error in eigen(corr) : non-square matrix in 'eigen'

Does anyone know how to get past this?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `order` argument. Seeing it seems you want xlabels, perhaps `corrplot(cormat,method="color",order="original")` is the output you're looking for?

Comment: The problem definitely is in the `order` argument as the error only comes up while using it. The "original" ordering seems to order the variables as they appear in the original `df` and not as they appear in the phylogram. So, sadly, that is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Maybe try `corrplot(cormat[xlabels,xlabels],method="color")` to reorder the rows and columns of cormat according to `xlabels`, and then plot it with the default `order`.